# How to use SUM along with LOOKUP function

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sum, lookup

In my SSRS report I have two tables: Losses(Table2) and Earned Premiums(Table 1), both coming from different datasets. I need to calculate ratios based on those Losses and Earned Premiums for each month and year. For that I used LOOKUP function and it works fine:

```
SUM(Fields!PaidLosses.Value) / Lookup(Fields!AccidentYearNum.Value & Fields!AccidentMonthNum.Value, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthStartRisk.Value, Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages")
```

[image]

But now I need to calculate `TOTALS`. Which is Total Losses for each month and year divided by Total Earned Premium for each month and year. 
Based on this article

[http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/salvoz-sql/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLpDJ.png)

I inserteded this Custome Code:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
If items Is Nothing Then
Return Nothing
End If
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
ct = 0
For Each item As Object In items
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
ct += 1
Next
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function
```

And now I am using this expression:

```
=SUM(Fields!PaidLosses.Value) / Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!AccidentYearNum.Value & Fields!AccidentMonthNum.Value, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthStartRisk.Value, Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages"))
```

But that doesnt give me correct answer for some reason. 
[image]
What am I missing here?

Comment: The expression may need to change to this: `=SUM(Fields!PaidLosses.Value) / Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!AccidentYearNum.Value, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value, Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages"))`

Comment: OMG!!! You just made my day!!!! Thank you very much!!! You are right, months are not in a group anymore.  I feel so dumb now :)

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: The expression for the total in the 3rd matrix needs some adjustment.

```
=SUM(Fields!PaidLosses.Value) / Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!AccidentYearNum.Value, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value, Fields!EarnedPremium.Value, "EarnedAllCoverages"))
```

The total is rolling up to the year, so the months are no longer needed.